# UNIX - need help in grep command

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I am trying to change the copyrights in a repository, i mean change the old copyrights to new copyrights for example copyrights 2008 to copyrights 2012,

so what i want to do is to find,

1. How many files have 2 copyrights
2. How many files do not have any copyrights in them
3. How many files have single, old copyrights in them

I was able to achieve 
questions 2 by using `grep -vir copyright *`, and 
question 3 by using `grep -rni copyright *`

how do I list out all the files with 2 copyrights in them?

Comment: There is no good reason for closing shell programming questions as off-topic on SO; shell programming is on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably 3, 4, or more copyrights are as troublesome as 2?

You can use `grep` to count, and then again to filter out the counts of 1:

```
grep -irc copyright * | grep -v '^ *1 '
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [uniq](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uniq) with the `-c` flag. i.e. `grep copyright * | uniq -c | egrep -v '^1'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `xargs` to get the number of copyright lines for all files:

```
ls * | xargs -I % sh -c "echo %; grep -c 'copyright' %"
```

Comment: We can discuss another time why processing the output of `ls` is perilous; for now, let's assume it is OK. However, that's a complicated way of doing it. You could simply write `grep -c copyright /dev/null *` (which avoids the problems with `ls`).  The `/dev/null` ensures that the file names are printed (but `/dev/null` won't show up in the output because it doesn't contain a copyright notice). IOW, there's no need to use `xargs`, nor to invoke `grep` multiple times (unless your folder contains so many files that you can't safely use `*`, but the question clearly implies that is not an issue).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Actually, `grep -c copyright *` works just fine. `grep -c copyright /dev/null *` prints a line for `/dev/null` too (with 0, of course), at least in `bash` I'm using. I agree that `xargs` is totally unnecessary here, my mind must have been wandering...

Comment: `grep -c copyright *` works fine if there is more than one file to process; if there's only one file, its name won't be shown.  The `/dev/null` trick (which can be used to good effect with `xargs` too) ensures there are at least two files on the command line, so the names are echoed.